# How to Solve: promise rejection: TypeError: payload.action.type.startsWith is not a function. In 'payload.action.type.startsWith("Navigation")

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have the following pieces of code.

- **ProductsReducer.js**:

```js
// Actions
export const ADD_PRODUCT = "products.add";

const initialState = {
  products: {}
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PRODUCT: {
        return {...state, payload: action.payload}
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

- **ProductsActions.js**:

```js
import ADD_PRODUCT from '../reducers/ProductsReducer'


export const addFavoriteProduct = (product) => {
  return async(dispatch, getState) => {
    const newProduct = product

    await dispatch({type: ADD_PRODUCT, payload:newProduct})

    return true
  }
}
```

I was trying to do a dispatch of the default action in **ProductsActions.js**, but this not working. I got this error:
[image: Promise Rejection by TypeError]

Answer (score 0):

As **ProductsReducer.js** contains a named export called `ADD_PRODUCT` the **import** must be:

```js
import {ADD_PRODUCT} from '../reducers/FavoriteReducer'
```

Because `import ADD_PRODUCT ...` only works if `ADD_PRODUCT` has the **default export**.